# Método add() não adiciona TimeSpan ao DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Criei um DateTime com alguns valores iniciados no construtor, mas quando adiciono um TimeSpan com alguns valores, ele não adiciona juntamente com a data.

Estou usando o método do DateTime para adicionar um TimeSpan, mas não esta funcionando pois o horário fica zerado, tem outra forma de fazer além dessa ? 
Ou o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(5,5,0);

    var data = new DateTime(2017,8,5);

    data.Add(timeSpan);

    Console.WriteLine(data);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Aqui deu certo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2R6rvB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) é uma estrutura(`struct`) que representa um instante no tempo.

A representação/valor de um determinado instante no tempo não muda, é aquele e não outro. Para garantir que isso seja assim a `struct DateTime` é implementada de forma a ser imutável.

Assim, o método [add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx) de DateTime não altera o objecto mas sim retorna um novo DateTime com o valor do TimeSpan adicionado.

Deve por isso usar o retorno do método.

Pode guardá-lo numa variável e usá-la no WriteLine

```
var dateTimeWithTimeSpanAdded = d.Add(ts);
Console.WriteLine(dateTimeWithTimeSpanAdded);
```

ou usar o retorno directamente

```
Console.WriteLine(d.Add(ts));
```

Comment: Só põe como ficaria.